# Ошибка multiple values for argument при вызове функции

Tags: python, функции

Можете объяснить, почему не работает конструкция вызова функции вида:

```py
def foo(a, b, c=-20, *args):
    print(a, b, c, args)

tup = (1, 2, 3, 4)
foo(1,2,c=100,*tup)
```

Если `с` у меня позиционный аргумент со стандартным значением `-20`, то почему я не могу вызвать функцию с указанием `с=100` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Позиционный аргумент (*args) следует за именованным аргументом (c = 100) в этом и ошибка.
Именованный аргумент

```py
def foo(a, b, *args, c=-20):
    print(a, b, c, args)

tup = (1, 2, 3, 4)
foo(1,2,tup, c = 100) # Передан именованный аргумент
```

Позиционный аргумент

```py
def foo(a, b, c=-20, *args):
    print(a, b, c, args)

tup = (1, 2, 3, 4)
foo(1,2,100,*tup) # передается позиционный аргумент
```

Comment: Но почему в определении функции c=-20 считается keyword only аргументом, а не позиционным со стандартным значением, который и должен стоять перед *args?

Comment: Если бы было так, то в моём примере не сработал бы вызов: foo(1,2,100,*tup)

Comment: При этом 100 != с. В армгементе `с` вы передается -20. А 100 относится к args. Вывод будет `1 2 -20 (100, (1, 2, 3, 4))`. Тоесть передать параметр `с` вы можете только явно указав его имя .

Comment: Нет, вот результат: http://pythontutor.ru/visualizer/saved/ae75d05dc0/ Я передал 100 "c" без явного указания имени. Это значит, что "с" не стала keyword only аргументом. Значит ответ на вопрос в другом.

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить этот код в консоли итог будет другим.

Comment: Выполнил, такой же результат.

Comment: Да я запустил версию которую привел в ответе, поэтому разница в показаниях ). В первом случае вы передаете позиционные аргумент, а во втором именованый.

Comment: В общем, выходит нельзя в позиционный запихивать именнованный вместе с пачкой *args. Наверное, мой пример из области плохого кода и лучше так не делать.